# Can not enter Data from multipage form

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Here, I want to insert data in database from multi-page form.

I am storing data in $_SESSION in page 1(createfinal.php) and page 2(personalfinal.php) and trying store directly the data of page 3(socialfinal.php).
    but I am getting database error called Message:
 Undefined variable: name_of_the_variable.

You can also suggest me other method by which i can make my code as small as possible.

Here is brief code::

controller Users:

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Controller
{

    public function viewinsert1()
    {

        $this->load->view('createfinal');
    }

    public function viewinsert2()
    {

        $this->load->view('personalfinal');
    }

    public function viewinsert3()
    {

        $this->load->view('socialfinal');
    }

    public function viewupdate()
    {

        $this->load->view('view_update');
    }

    public function viewdelete()
    {

        $this->load->view('view_delete');
    }

    public function show()
    {
        // $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->user_model->get_users();


        $this->load->view('user_view', $data);

        // foreach ($result as $object) 
        // {
        //  echo $object->id . "</br>"; 
        // }
    }

    // public function insert()
    // {

    //  $username = "Peter";
    //  $password = "12345";
    //  $this->user_model->create_users([
    //      'username' => $username,
    //      'password' => $password
    //      ]);
    // }

    public function insert()
    {
        // echo $this->input->post('password') . "</br>";
        // echo $_POST['username'];


        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
        $_SESSION['cpass'] = $cpass;
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $lname;
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
        $_SESSION['address'] = $address;

        $data = array(
                    'email' => $email,
                    'firstname' => $fname,
                    'lastname' => $lname,
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
                    'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
                    'googleplus' => $this->input->post('gplus'),
                    'password' => $pass,
                    'confirm' => $cpass, 
                    );

        // echo var_dump($data);


        $result = $this->user_model->create_users($data);

        $this->load->view('createfinal');

        echo "<h1>The data has been inserted</h1>";
    }


    public function update()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['update'])) 
        {

            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                          );

            $this->user_model->update_users($data, $id);

            echo "<h1> Data is updated successfully:) </h1>";
            $this->load->view('view_update');
        }
        else
        {

            echo "Oops! There is something wrong!";
        }

    }

    public function delete()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) 
        {

            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $this->user_model->delete_users($id);

            echo "<h1>The data has been deleted.</h1>";

        }
        else
        {

            echo "<h3>No Such data exist!</h3>";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Model user_model:

```
<?php

class User_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function get_users()
    {
        // $this->db->where([
        //  'id' => $user_id,
        //  'username' => $username
        //  ]);

        //$this->db->where('id', $user_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result(); 

        // $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

        //return $query->num_rows(); //returns the number of rows


    }

    public function create_users($data)
    {

        return $this->db->insert('users', $data);

    }

    public function update_users($data, $id)
    {

        $this->db->where(['id'=>$id]);
        $this->db->update('users', $data);
    }

    public function delete_users($id)
    {
        $this->db->where(['id' => $id]);
        $this->db->delete('users');
    }
}
?>
```

Here are the three views of three pages:
page 1(createfinal.php):

```
<?php

session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" action="viewinsert2" method="post">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        <input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>


</body>
</html>
```

page 2(personalfinal.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$cpass = $_POST['cpass'];

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
$_SESSION['cpass'] = $cpass;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" method="post" action="viewinsert3">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li>Account Setup</li>
        <li class="active">Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

page 3(socialfinal.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];


$_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
$_SESSION['lname'] = $lname;
$_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
$_SESSION['address'] = $address;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" method="post" action="insert">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li>Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
        <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
        <input type="submit" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Image of the error:
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/izsjY.png

Comment: In insert() function where did you define the $email,$pass ... variables

Comment: i've been defined in the view of pages..

Comment: You can't set  variables in the view and then access them in the controller beside the best approach would be, send the data as POST/GET request from the view and then access it in the controller using `$this->input->post('email');

Comment: ok, thankx but as i said new database error is being generated which is 1054

Comment: @DharaVihol, show the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['email']);` placed right after `session_start()` within page 3(socialfinal.php)

Comment: it is giving the true answer

Comment: 'email' is not equal to 'Email'.

Comment: Yup, but I have not used Email anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In your user controller try adjusting insert method as illustrated below.

```
public function insert()
{
    // echo $this->input->post('password') . "</br>";
    // echo $_POST['username'];

    #Set the provided data into variables
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $pass  = $this->input->post('pass');
    $cpass = $this->input->post('cpass');
    $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
    $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
    $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');

    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
    $_SESSION['cpass'] = $cpass;
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
    $_SESSION['lname'] = $lname;
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
    $_SESSION['address'] = $address;

    $data = array(
                'email' => $email,
                'firstname' => $fname,
                'lastname' => $lname,
                'phone' => $phone,
                'address' => $address,
                'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
                'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
                'googleplus' => $this->input->post('gplus'),
                'password' => $pass,
                'confirm' => $cpass, 
                );

    // echo var_dump($data);


    $result = $this->user_model->create_users($data);

    $this->load->view('createfinal');

    echo "<h1>The data has been inserted</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Ok. THe actual error is gone. Thank you for that but it is still not getting the data of page 1 and page 2..

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Actually i was trying to insert the data in my old database table which do not contain the Column name with email. Therefore, i was getting the error. Thank you So much for your precious help. :)